# Help with complex join conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, join

I have the following mysql table schema:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `network`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `contexts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contexts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `neurons`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `neurons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `synapses`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `synapses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `context_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strength` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

What SQL can I write to get all Neurons associated with a specified context along with the sum of the strength column for the synapses associated with each neuron?

I'm using the following query, which returns the sum of the strength of the synapses associated with one neuron. I need to get information for all of the neurons:

```
/* This query finds how strongly the neuron with id 1 is connected to the context with keyword ice cream*/

SELECT SUM(strength) AS Strength FROM
synapses
JOIN contexts AS Context ON synapses.context_id = Context.id
JOIN neurons AS Neuron ON Neuron.id = synapses.n1_id OR Neuron.id = synapses.n2_id
WHERE Neuron.id = 1 AND Context.keyword = 'ice cream'
```

For example, that query returns one row, where Strength is 2. Ideally, I could have one column for the neurons.id, one for neurons.name, and one for SUM(synapses.strength) with one record for each distinct neuron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          n.*,
          COALESCE(x.strength, 0) AS strength
     FROM NEURONS n
     JOIN SYNAPSES s ON n.id IN (s.n1_id, s.n2_id)
     JOIN CONTEXTS c ON c.id = s.context_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.id AS c_id,
                  n.id AS n_id,
                  SUM(strength) AS Strength 
             FROM SYNAPSES s
             JOIN CONTEXTS c ON c.id = s.context_id
             JOIN NEURONS n ON n.id IN (s.n1_id, s.n2_id)
         GROUP BY c.id, n.id) x ON x.c_id = c.id
                               AND x.n_id = n.id
```

Comment: This query is way faster. I tried both with an added WHERE context.keyword LIKE '%ice%'... Mike's sql took 0.0218 s. Ponies's code took 0.0007 s. Why is this query so much faster?

Comment: @Adam: Probably has to do with different syntax (swapped out OR for an IN clause).  Also, less criteria to group on for the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT contexts.keyword, neurons.id, neurons.name, SUM(synapses.strength)
FROM neurons
INNER JOIN synapses ON neurons.id = synapses.n1_id OR neurons.id = synapses.n2_id
INNER JOIN contexts ON synapses.context_id = contexts.id
GROUP BY contexts.keyword, neurons.id, neurons.name
```

Comment: I get the following error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN synapses ON neurons.id = synapses.n1_id OR neurons.id = synapses.n2_i' at line 3

Comment: fixed? :) i just had to remove some commas

Comment: Nice work - I had to change context to contexts in a couple of locations, but it works great. Thanks, Mike. +1.

Comment: Your code worked, but the sql below is faster... Thanks for the help :)